# Selenium - chromeDriver u'unknown error : chrome field to start

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I'm pretty new in selenium and getting an error with ChromeWebDriver.

I'm using: Chrome 36, ChromeWebDriver 2.10, Windows 7

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

webD = webdriver.Chrome();
```

But I get the response

```
unknown error : chrome field to start
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to download the chrome executable driver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and set the executable path accordingly.
Sample Python Code :

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chromedriver = "./chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
print driver.title
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

For more information and end to end script follow
[Reference](http://www.guguncube.com/2983/python-testing-selenium-with-google-chrome)